# Detect ions in water using impedance spectroscopy

Tags: water, dielectric, electrical-resistance

I would like to check the presence of Na, Ca or other ions dissolved in water using impedance spectroscopy.

I was thinking that because the ions have different masses they will have different dielectric relaxation frequencies.
Hence, performing impedance spectroscopy to the water sample and investigating the intensity of the dielectric relaxation peaks I could be able to match them to the presence of the different ions.

I believe that this is theoretically possible, but is it technically feasible to achieve a "good" sensibility and selectivity?

Comment: such analysis is being done and you can consult/see    http://www.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/acnew/department/pages/teaching/pages/teaching__wintersemester__2012_2013/cornelia_breitkopf__impedance_spectroscopy__121207.pdf

Comment: @drvrm I read the presentation of that link, but I couldn't find anything that could help answer this question. It makes a nice introduction to impedance spectroscopy, but it doesn't cover ion detection in water...

Comment: Then you can also see <http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304386X13001138>..actually any other study will not be exactly handling your  specific  issue but if the technique is being used for say Na-chloride ion ,then on those lines one can proceed.

Comment: @drvrm I really thank you for your comment, but I am sorry to say that I couldn't find that paper useful for this problem. If I well understood, this paper analyses the response of a passive layer, not the "bulk" of a solution, and it doesn't really relate a dielectric relaxation frequency with the Na element.

Comment: I will be on the look out in literature and place it.